# what is the fastest way to kill a troll in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So in Skyrim going to one town near a river a regular troll is outside the entrance down the slope of the hill and you have to walk past him I ran using my whirlwind sprint you learn from the greybeards... After running I had made it to the town all the towns people pulled out weapons and it turns out the troll had followed me from the river to the town itself and this was when I was over encumbered yet the cool down was fairly quick so I was a ways ahead and on your way to the greybeards the first time you pass by a frost troll I would really like to level some skills against them yet I also want it to be quick any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Its Best to get a flame Enchanted weapon ,correct me if im wrong but i think theres a tool tip when the game is loading that details what i just said aswell. The flame enchanted weapon may be a bit expensive at low evels but you can use a 2-H weapon instead.

Comment: Love me a Fiery Soul Trap enchantment.  +10 Flame Damage, Fill a soul gem, and you can get thousands of hits from a single recharge.  It's my go-to weapon enchant for all but end game.

Comment: Yup! makes enemies fall!

Answer (score 0):

I would kill a troll using a strong shield and your strongest one-handed weapon and using power attacks to stop the troll from attacking.  Another good way to kill it would be to shoot it from a safe place and switch to the shield and weapon after weakening it if you have to.